# Python vector similarity (Scipy or etc)

Tags: python, vector, scipy, compare, similarity

I am currently using cosine, euclidean, and chebyshev etc similarity functions in scipy.

The problem is that it only measures the distance between two vectors. That means it will call the function n times if I have n set of vectors to comparing to get the distance from one given vectors set to n sets of vectors.

Is there any library or a better way to do this work faster? Or less call the function?

Make sure that this aims to reduce the computation time ...

Comment: Probably you are looking for something that is already implemented in `sckit-learn` or SciPy's [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html)

Comment: a version of KDTree is also available in [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html)

Comment: I fail to see how a KDTree would cut down computation time if OP wants all distances, not just the distances to the nearest neighbours.